# Distillation of oxalyl chloride

Tags: safety, distillation

May I use water as a condensing medium while distilling out oxalyl chloride?

As oxalyl chloride reacts with water and the products are $\ce{HCl},$ $\ce{CO}$ and $\ce{CO2},$ when there is a leak or breakage of condenser shell/tube separating water and oxalyl chloride, there may be liberation of toxic gases causing the situation more unsafe.

Comment: It should be safe enough to use water as your coolant, check that your water hoses a securely attached, conduct the distillation in an uncluttered fume hood if possible.